# Set::extract Cakephp change format of the returned array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am new to cake so please be patient.
I have this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CoursesLessons] => Array
            (
                [id] => 108
                [course_id] => 88
                [lesson_id] => 6
                [deleted] => 
            )

        [UserLessonsCompleted] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [courses_lessons_id] => 108
                        [user_id] => 75
                        [created] => 2015-01-27 14:04:31
                        [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [completed_at] => 2015-02-03 14:04:45
                        [homework_downloaded_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [deleted] => 
                    )

            )

    )

 //and so on
```

I would like to exctract the `UserLessonsCompleted completed at`.
What I am trying to do is:

```
$stringOfIdsCompleted =  Set::extract($coursesLessons, '{n}.UserLessonsCompleted.{n}.completed_at');
```

my problem is that they array that is returned is:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-02-03 14:04:45
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2015-02-06 15:08:01
    )
//and so on
```

while I would like something as:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [completed_at] => 2015-02-03 14:04:45
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [completed_at] => 2015-02-06 15:08:01
    )
```

Any help on how to achieve this? thank you in advance for help

here is how i retrieve my data:

```
$coursesLessons = $this->CoursesLessons->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'CoursesLessons.course_id' => $courseId,
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'UserLessonsCompleted' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'UserLessonsCompleted.user_id' => $userId,
                ),
            ), 
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your find method add fields property, like:

```
$coursesLessons = $this->CoursesLessons->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'CoursesLessons.course_id' => $courseId,
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'UserLessonsCompleted' => array(
            'fields' => array('UserLessonsCompleted.created_at'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserLessonsCompleted.user_id' => $userId,
            ),
        ), 
    )
));
```

then extract:

```
$stringOfIdsCompleted =  Set::extract($coursesLessons, '{n}.UserLessonsCompleted');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this would be to handle it in the initial find in your controller / model using either the `fields` or the `contain` option, something like this:

```
$this->CoursesLesson->find('all', 
    array('contain' => array('UserLessonsCompleted.created_at'))
);
```

You will need to ensure that you have the "containable" behaviour attached (I attach it to my AppModel as I use it all the time).

If you cant work this out post your controller code and I will be able to give you a more tailored answer :)

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, see edited question for how I am retrieving the data

Comment: @Salines answer below is bang on :)